# Magento: Call custom phtml in list.phtml via XML

Tags: xml, magento, module, block

In Magento, I'm trying to show a phtml a custom module in list.phtml.
My xml looks like this:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="content">
            <block type="my_prevenda/prevendalist" name="prevenda" as="prevenda" template="prevenda/prevenda_list.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

And I call like this:`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('prevenda') ?>`

But this method only shou in view.phtml.
How do I appear in list.phtml?
Will remain with the product name

I Tks all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list"><!-- need to add to the correct parent block -->
                <block type="my_prevenda/prevendalist"
                       name="prevenda" as="prevenda"
                       template="prevenda/prevenda_list.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. I think the problem is here: <catalog_category_default> perhaps should not be this reference, but I have no idea what is.

Comment: Mesmo alterando para <default> não aparece.

Comment: Even changing to <default> not appear.

Comment: `<default>` won't work because the `product_list` block directive is part of the `catalog_category_default` handle. Are you refreshing the layout XML cache? If you break (add invalid syntax to) your layout XML, do you see a parse error? If not, enable developer mode and troubleshoot that issue.

Comment: Sorry, the cache was disabled but do not know why it did not work. I released the cache in admin and it worked. Thank you!!

Comment: In list.phtml can not pick which attributes are handled in the Block. Do you know a solution for this? Please

Comment: @LaercioSilva You should ask a new question regarding list.phtml and attributes rather than add to the current one :-)